# Can VS Code publish to the Google Artifact Registry?

Tags: vscode-extensions, google-artifact-registry

I am new to VS Code and wondering if it is possible to configure the Docker extension to publish directly to the Google Artifact Registry.  It seems like it should be possible because VS Code can connect to generic registries, but I cannot find any relevant documentation.

Comment: Have you check on this documentation [Deploy a service in Cloud Code for VS Code](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/vscode/deploy-service) and this [post](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-vscode/issues/500#issuecomment-977177836) from github?

Comment: @SarahRemo Thank you for your response. Yes, but I did not get far because I do not use Anthos. "Cloud Code can only deploy to Cloud Run for Anthos if Cloud Run for Anthos is enabled as a feature on the GKE cluster."

Comment: to clarify you, that note on the documentation will apply if you only select Cloud Run for Anthos.

Comment: But if you choose Cloud Run(fully managed) as a deployment platform you can use Cloud Code extension for VS Code that build your image, pushes it to the registry, and deploys your service to Cloud Run. It states here in [step 9](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/vscode/deploy-service#:~:text=Cloud%20Code%20for%20VS%20Code%20builds%20your%20image%2C%20pushes%20it%20to%20the%20registry%2C%20and%20deploys%20your%20service%20to%20Cloud%20Run.%20Your%20service%20is%20now%20live!).

Comment: Thank you.  I will try and let you know!